# Order a SQL SELECT by a IN selection

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a SELECT based on a IN

I want to order the extraction in the same order I made the IN. How can I make it?

```
SELECT * FROM BOLLER1 WHERE BOLR1_KT1 IN ('TM2019000026000010',
'TM2019000024700010',
'TM2019000024700070',
'TM2019000024700080',
'Mr2019000000400010',
'TM2019000024700110',
'TM2019000024700100',
'TM2019000024700120',
'TM2019000026000020',
'TM2019000024700040',
'TM2019000024700090',
'Mj2019000000100010',
'Ma2019000003200020',
'Ma2019000000100020',
'TM2019000025700010',
'Mj2019000000400010',
'Mj2019000001000010',
'Mj2019000002000010',
'Ma2020000005000010',
'Mj2019000004800010',
'TM2019000026000010',
'TM2019000024700010',
'TM2019000024700110',
'TM2019000024700100',
'TM2019000026000020',
'TM2019000024700040',
'TM2019000024700090',
'TM2019000024700120',
'TM2019000024700080',
'TM2019000026300010',
'TM2019000024700050',
'Mj2019000005400010',
'Mj2019000005400010',
'Mg2019000008700020',
'MB2020000006800120',
'Ma2020000001200020',
'Mj2019000023300040',
'Mj2019000006900010',
'Mj2019000007100010',
'TM2019000004500010',
'Mj2019000007400010',
'Mj2019000007000010',
'Mf2019000004700060',
'Mf2019000004700110',
'Ma2020000001200020',
'Mj2019000023300040',
'Mj2019000007200010',
'Mj2019000007200090',
'Mj2019000010100010',
'Mf2019000004700060',
'Mf2019000004700110',
'Mj2019000007400010',
'Mj2019000007000010',
'Ma2020000001200020',
'Mj2019000023300040',
'Mj2019000006400010',
'Mj2019000002600010',
'Mj2019000004600010',
'Mj2019000007700010',
'Mj2019000006500010',
'Mg2019000000200140',
'TM2019000026000010',
'TM2019000024700010',
'TM2019000024700110',
'TM2019000024700100',
'Mg2018000001600020',
'MB2018000000300020',
'TM2019000026000020',
'TM2019000024700040',
'TM2019000024700090',
'Mj2019000012000010',
'Mg2018000001600020',
'MB2019000010700020',
'TM2019000024700050',
'Mj2019000005400010',
'MB2020000006800120',
'Mg2019000022700040',
'Mj2019000000400010',
'Mj2019000023300040',
'Ma2020000001200020',
'Mg2019000016600260',
'Mf2019000004700060',
'Mf2019000004700110',
'Mg2019000018600170',
'Mj2019000011800010',
'Mj2019000007100010',
'Mg2019000013200020',
'Mj2019000006100010',
'Ma2019000001500020',
'Mg2018000000700020',
'Mj2019000013600010',
'Mj2019000010300010',
'Mg2018000001600020',
'Mf2019000004700020',
'Mj2019000002600010',
'Mg2019000000200140',
'Mj2019000023300040',
'Ma2020000001200020',
'Mf2019000004700060',
'Mf2019000004700110',
'Mj2019000013100010',
'Mg2019000008300020',
'Mj2019000010300010',
'Mg2019000002600040',
'Mg2019000025900020',
'Mj2019000013000010',
'Mg2018000001600020',
'Mg2018000001600020',
'Mg2019000000200140',
'Mv2020000001500010',
'Mj2019000010300010',
'Mg2018000001600020',
'Mf2019000003600020',
'Ma2020000001200020',
'Mf2019000004700060',
'Mf2019000004700110',
'Ma2019000000300020',
'TM2019000026300010',
'Mv2019000000100010',
'Mj2019000007100010',
'Mj2019000014100010',
'Mj2019000006500010',
'Mf2019000004700020',
'Mv2020000001500010',
'Ma2019000001800020',
'TM2019000026000010',
'MB2019000010700020',
'Mg2019000022700040',
'TM2019000024700110',
'TM2019000024700100',
'TM2019000024700050',
'Mj2019000005400010',
'TM2019000024700120',
'TM2019000026000020',
'TM2019000024700040',
'TM2019000024700090',
'Mg2019000000200140',
'TM2019000024700010',
'TM2019000025700010',
'Ma2019000000600020',
'Ma2019000000600020',
'Mf2019000003600020',
'Ma2020000001200020',
'Mf2019000004700060',
'Mf2019000004700110',
'Mj2019000014100010',
'Mv2020000001500010',
'Ma2019000001400020',
'Mf2019000004700020',
'Mv2020000001500010',
'Mg2018000001600020',
'Ma2019000002700020',
'Ma2020000000800020',
'Mv2019000000100010',
'Mg2019000018600170',
'Mg2019000016600260',
'Mg2019000000200140',
'Ma2019000002600020',
'Mj2020000001600010',
'Mv2020000001100010',
'Mj2019000001700010',
'Ma2019000003300020',
'TM2019000026300010',
'TM2019000025700010',
'Mg2019000008700020',
'TM2019000026300010',
'Mg2018000001600020',
'TM2019000024700010',
'Mj2020000012700010',
'PN2019000004900010',
'TM2019000024700110',
'TM2019000024700100',
'TM2019000024700050',
'PN2019000003700010',
'Ml2018000000300010',
'Mw2019000000100010',
'Mj2019000004700010',
'TM2019000026000020',
'TM2019000024700040',
'TM2019000024700090',
'Ma2020000000400020',
'Ma2020000004300010',
'Ma2020000004300010',
'Ma2019000003400020',
'TM2019000026300010',
'Ml2020000007500010',
'Ma2020000000400020',
'MB2019000037000020',
'Ma2020000000600020',
'Ma2020000005100010',
'Ma2020000005100010',
'Ma2020000000100020',
'Ma2020000000800020',
'TM2019000024700010',
'MB2019000037000020',
'TM2019000025200010',
'TM2019000024700110',
'TM2019000024700050',
'Ml2018000000300010',
'PN2019000003700010',
'TM2019000026000020',
'TM2019000024700040',
'TM2019000024700090',
'Mr2020000000400010',
'TM2019000024700100',
'PN2019000002400010',
'Mv2020000003100010',
'TM2019000025000010',
'Ma2020000000700020',
'Mv2020000000900010',
'Mv2020000000500010',
'Mv2020000000800010',
'Mv2020000000400010',
'Mv2020000000700010',
'Mb2020000001100010',
'Mw2020000001100010',
'Ma2020000001600020',
'Mw2020000001000010',
'TM2019000026300010',
'Mv2020000001100010',
'Ma2020000001200020',
'Mj2020000006800010',
'Ma2020000002100020',
'Mb2020000001400010',
'Ma2020000002000020',
'Mb2020000001300010',
'Ma2020000000700020',
'Mw2020000001200010',
'Ma2020000001600020',
'Mj2020000006800010',
'Mv2020000001100010',
'Mv2020000001100010',
'Ma2020000001200020',
'Mj2019000023300040',
'Ma2020000002300020',
'Ma2020000002300020',
'Mf2019000004700060',
'Ma2020000002500040',
'Mv2020000001500010',
'Mv2020000001500010',
'Mj2020000001200010',
'Mr2020000000100010',
'Mw2020000001500010',
'Ma2020000002000020',
'Ma2020000002000100',
'Mb2020000001500010',
'Ma2019000003600020',
'Mg2019000006000020',
'Ma2020000000900080',
'Mw2020000001600010',
'Mw2020000001600010',
'Mj2020000001200010',
'Ma2020000002300020',
'Mj2019000023300040',
'Ma2020000002400020',
'Ma2020000002500040',
'Ma2020000001200020',
'Mj2020000006800010',
'Ma2020000002100020',
'Mw2020000001700010',
'Ml2020000003300010',
'TM2019000024700100',
'TM2019000024700010',
'Mj2019000012400010',
'Ma2020000001600020',
'TM2019000024700110',
'TM2019000024700100',
'TM2019000024700050',
'Ma2020000001900020',
'Mj2019000005400010',
'Mv2019000000100010',
'Mr2019000000200010',
'Mr2020000000100010',
'TM2019000026000020',
'TM2019000024700040',
'TM2019000024700090',
'Mw2020000001800010',
'Mb2020000002000010',
'Mg2019000006000020',
'Mg2020000011900020',
'Ma2020000002000100',
'Ma2020000002000020',
'Ma2019000003600020',
'Ma2020000002300020',
'TM2020000002600010',
'Ma2020000002400020',
'Ma2020000002500040',
'Mv2020000001500010',
'Ma2020000003200010',
'Ma2020000002000020',
'Ma2020000002000100',
'Mr2020000000100010',
'Ma2019000003600020',
'Ma2020000002700020',
'Mv2020000001300010',
'Ma2020000001200020',
'Ma2020000001200020',
'Ma2020000002400020',
'Ma2020000002400020',
'Ma2020000002400020',
'Mv2020000001500010',
'Mv2020000002500010',
'Ma2020000002000020',
'Ma2020000002000100',
'Ma2020000003400010',
'Ma2020000003600010',
'Mv2020000002600010',
'Mv2020000002800010',
'Mv2020000003000010',
'Mv2020000002300010',
'Ma2020000002000020',
'Ma2020000002000100',
'Ma2020000003600010',
'Mv2020000002700010',
'TM2019000024700010',
'TM2019000024700100',
'Mg2019000022700040',
'Mr2020000000600010',
'TM2019000024700110',
'Mr2020000000400010',
'TM2019000024700050',
'Mj2019000005400010',
'Mv2019000000100010',
'Ma2020000001200020',
'Ma2020000001200020',
'Ma2020000002300020',
'Ma2020000002300020',
'Ma2020000002300020',
'Ma2020000004400040',
'Ma2020000004400040',
'TM2019000026000020',
'TM2019000024700040',
'TM2019000024700090',
'Mr2020000000300010',
'Ma2020000004600010',
'Mv2020000003300010',
'Mv2020000003200010',
'Ma2020000003900010',
'Ma2020000002000020',
'Ma2020000002000100',
'Ma2020000003600010',
'Mv2020000001500010',
'Mv2020000001500010',
'Ma2022000004200010',
'Ma2020000004400040',
'Ma2020000004400040',
'Ma2020000001200020',
'Ma2020000001200020',
'Ml2020000002700040',
'Ml2020000002700040',
'Ml2020000002700040',
'Ma2020000004700010',
'Ma2019000003600020',
'Mv2020000003700010',
'Mv2020000003600010',
'Ma2020000004100010',
'Mv2020000003800010',
'Mv2020000001500010',
'Mj2019000023300040',
'Ma2020000002300020',
'Mf2019000004700060',
'Ma2020000002500040',
'Ma2020000004800010',
'Mr2020000001200010',
'Ma2020000004300010',
'Mj2020000007400010',
'Mr2020000000900010',
'Ma2020000005100010',
'Mf2020000010700020',
'Ma2020000005200010',
'Ma2020000005000010',
'Ma2020000005500010',
'Ms2020000000600010',
'Ma2020000002000020',
'Ma2020000002000100',
'Mv2020000001500010',
'Ma2020000005700010',
'Mr2020000000700010',
'Ma2020000005600010',
'Ma2020000005500010',
'Ma2021000000100010',
'Ma2019000003600020',
'Ma2020000002000020',
'Ma2020000002000100',
'Ms2020000000600010',
'Ma2021000000300010',
'Ma2021000000500010',
'Mv2021000000200010',
'Ma2021000000800010',
'Ma2019000003600020',
'Ms2020000000600010',
'Ma2021000000900010',
'Mv2021000000700010',
'TM2019000026300010',
'Ma2019000003600020',
'Mv2020000001100010',
'Mv2021000000500010',
'Ma2021000001500010',
'Ma2021000001400010',
'Mr2020000000700010',
'Mr2021000000100010',
'Mj2019000012400010',
'Mr2020000000600010',
'Mr2020000000400010',
'Mv2019000000100010',
'Mr2019000000200010',
'Mr2020000000300010',
'Mr2020000000300010',
'Ms2020000000600010',
'Mj2021000005100010',
'Mr2021000000500010',
'Ma2019000003600020',
'Mv2020000002500010',
'Mg2020000035400020',
'Ms2020000000600010',
'Ma2019000003600020',
'Mv2020000002900010',
'Mv2021000001100010',
'Ma2021000002000010',
'Ma2021000001900010',
'TM2020000002600010',
'Ma2020000002300020',
'Ma2020000002500040',
'Ma2020000002400020',
'Ma2021000002200010',
'Ma2021000002300010',
'Ma2021000002500010',
'Ma2019000000100020',
'Mv2021000000700010',
'Mv2021000001100010',
'TM2020000002600010',
'Ma2020000002400020',
'Ma2020000002500040',
'Mv2020000002900010',
'Ma2021000002300010',
'Ma2021000002600010',
'Mr2020000000700010',
'Mr2021000000100010',
'Mj2019000012400010',
'Mr2020000001100010',
'TM2020000003400010',
'Mj2021000005400010',
'Mv2019000000100010',
'Mr2019000000200010',
'Mv2021000001100010',
'TM2020000002600010',
'Ma2020000002400020',
'Ma2020000002500040',
'Mv2020000002900010',
'Ma2021000002200010',
'Ma2021000002300010',
'Ma2021000002600010',
'Mr2020000001200010',
'Ma2021000001200010',
'Ma2021000001200010',
'Mr2021000000500010',
'Ma2021000001800010',
'Ma2021000003600010',
'Mv2020000001100010',
'Ma2021000002200010',
'TM2020000002600010',
'Mj2019000023300010',
'Mj2019000023300020',
'Ma2021000002400010',
'Ma2021000002300010',
'Ma2020000002300020',
'Ma2021000001800010',
'Ma2021000003900010',
'Ma2021000003100010',
'Ma2021000003300010',
'Ma2021000003800010',
'Ma2021000003200010',
'Ma2021000002100010',
'Ma2021000002100010',
'Mv2021000001400010',
'Ma2021000002500010',
'Mv2021000001300010',
'Ma2021000003900010',
'Ma2021000001800010',
'Ma2021000003200010',
'Ma2021000003100010',
'Ma2021000002400010',
'Ma2021000003300010',
'Ms2020000000600010',
'Mv2021000001100010',
'Mv2021000001100010',
'Mv2020000001100010',
'Ma2021000002200010',
'Mj2019000023300040',
'Ma2020000002400020',
'Ma2020000002500040',
'Ma2021000002300010',
'Ma2020000002300020',
'Mr2021000000500010',
'Mr2020000000700010',
'TM2020000003400010',
'Ma2021000003300010',
'Ma2021000003100010',
'Ma2021000003900010',
'Ma2021000001800010',
'Ma2021000003200010',
'Ma2021000002300010',
'Ma2021000002400010',
'TM2020000002600010',
'Ma2021000002200010',
'Mv2021000001100010',
'Mv2020000001100010',
'Ms2020000000600010',
'Ma2021000004100010',
'Mv2020000001100010',
'Ma2021000002400010',
'Ma2021000001800010',
'Ma2021000004600010',
'Mf2019000006600020',
'Ma2021000004300010',
'Ma2021000001800010',
'Ma2021000002400010',
'Mv2021000001100010',
'Mj2021000005200010',
'Mr2021000000400010',
'Mj2019000005400010',
'Mr2020000000700010',
'Mr2021000000100010',
'Mj2019000012400010',
'TM2020000003200010',
'TM2020000003400010',
'Mv2019000000100010',
'Mr2019000000200010',
'TM2020000003300010',
'Ma2021000001800010',
'Ma2021000002400010',
'Mv2021000001000010',
'Mv2020000001100010',
'TM2019000026300010',
'Ma2021000004500010',
'Mv2020000001100010',
'Ma2021000002400010',
'Ma2021000001800010',
'Mj2021000016300010',
'Ma2022000000200010',
'Ma2022000000400010',
'Ma2022000000100010',
'Ma2022000001100010',
'Mv2022000000200010',
'Ma2022000001300010',
'TM2022000009400010',
'Mv2021000000900010',
'Mv2022000000100010',
'Ma2022000000500010',
'Ma2022000001100080',
'Ma2021000002400010',
'Ma2021000001800010',
'Mv2022000000300010',
'Mv2022000000400010',
'Mv2021000001000010',
'Ma2020000003000020',
'Ma2021000002500010',
'Ma2021000002400010',
'Mj2022000001400010',
'Mv2022000000400010',
'Mv2021000001000010',
'Ma2021000002400010',
'Ma2022000001500010',
'Ma2021000001800010',
'Ma2022000002200010',
'Ms2020000000600010',
'Ma2021000002300010',
'Ma2022000003200010',
'Ma2022000002800010',
'Mj2019000005400010',
'Mr2020000000700010',
'Mv2021000001000010',
'Ma2021000001800010',
'Mj2021000016300010',
'Mv2021000001000010',
'Ma2021000002400010',
'Ma2021000002500010',
'Ma2021000002300010',
'Ma2022000003200010',
'Ma2021000002300010',
'Mv2022000000400010',
'Mv2021000001000010',
'Ma2021000002400010',
'Ma2021000002500010',
'Ma2021000004800010',
'Ma2022000004100010',
'Mv2022000000400010',
'Mv2021000001000010',
'Ma2021000002400010',
'Ma2022000004100010',
'Ma2022000004200010',
'Ma2021000001800010',
'Ma2022000002700010',
'Ma2022000004000010',
'Ma2021000002300010',
'Ma2021000004800010',
'Mb2022000003000010',
'Mb2022000002900010',
'Ma2021000002500010',
'Ma2022000002900010',
'Mj2019000005400010',
'Mr2021000000100010',
'Mr2020000000700010',
'Mr2021000000500010',
'Mb2022000003200010',
'Mv2022000000400010',
'Mv2021000001000010',
'Mw2022000001000010',
'Ma2022000004300010',
'Ma2021000002500010',
'Mw2022000001100010',
'Mv2022000001200010',
'Mb2022000003400010',
'Mb2022000003500010')
```

I tried using ORDER BY statement but with no effects I'd like to obtain.

Comment: I doubt if its possible. You can put your values e.g. 'Mb2022000003500010' etc to the separate table, add number which you will use to sort as the second column and then perform a join between these two tables

Comment: Add an ordinal column to the list (using `select ... from dual`) and use `join` instead of `in`. `in` is a condition, it doesn't matter how the list is ordered for membership check.

Comment: And a side note: the question is clear even for 5 items, this long list is not readable and adds no value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
WITH dat AS 
(
  SELECT 'TM2019000026000010' AS val FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'TM2019000024700010' FROM dual UNION ALL
   ...
  SELECT 'Mj2019000023300040' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000001200020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mf2019000004700060' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mf2019000004700110' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mj2019000013100010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mg2019000008300020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mj2019000010300010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mg2019000002600040' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mg2019000025900020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mj2019000013000010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mg2018000001600020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mg2018000001600020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mg2019000000200140' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mv2020000001500010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mj2019000010300010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mg2018000001600020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mf2019000003600020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000001200020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mf2019000004700060' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mf2019000004700110' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2019000000300020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'TM2019000026300010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mv2019000000100010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mj2019000007100010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mj2019000014100010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mj2019000006500010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mf2019000004700020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mv2020000001500010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2019000001800020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'TM2019000026000010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'MB2019000010700020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mg2019000022700040' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'TM2019000024700110' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'TM2019000024700100' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'TM2019000024700050' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mj2019000005400010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'TM2019000024700120' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'TM2019000026000020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'TM2019000024700040' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'TM2019000024700090' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mg2019000000200140' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'TM2019000024700010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'TM2019000025700010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2019000000600020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2019000000600020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mf2019000003600020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000001200020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mf2019000004700060' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mf2019000004700110' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mj2019000014100010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mv2020000001500010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2019000001400020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mf2019000004700020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mv2020000001500010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mg2018000001600020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2019000002700020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000000800020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mv2019000000100010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mg2019000018600170' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mg2019000016600260' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mg2019000000200140' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2019000002600020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mj2020000001600010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mv2020000001100010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mj2019000001700010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2019000003300020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'TM2019000026300010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'TM2019000025700010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mg2019000008700020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'TM2019000026300010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mg2018000001600020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'TM2019000024700010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mj2020000012700010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'PN2019000004900010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'TM2019000024700110' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'TM2019000024700100' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'TM2019000024700050' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'PN2019000003700010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ml2018000000300010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mw2019000000100010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mj2019000004700010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'TM2019000026000020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'TM2019000024700040' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'TM2019000024700090' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000000400020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000004300010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000004300010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2019000003400020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'TM2019000026300010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ml2020000007500010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000000400020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'MB2019000037000020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000000600020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000005100010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000005100010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000000100020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000000800020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'TM2019000024700010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'MB2019000037000020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'TM2019000025200010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'TM2019000024700110' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'TM2019000024700050' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ml2018000000300010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'PN2019000003700010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'TM2019000026000020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'TM2019000024700040' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'TM2019000024700090' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mr2020000000400010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'TM2019000024700100' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'PN2019000002400010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mv2020000003100010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'TM2019000025000010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000000700020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mv2020000000900010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mv2020000000500010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mv2020000000800010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mv2020000000400010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mv2020000000700010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mb2020000001100010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mw2020000001100010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000001600020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mw2020000001000010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'TM2019000026300010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mv2020000001100010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000001200020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mj2020000006800010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000002100020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mb2020000001400010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000002000020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mb2020000001300010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000000700020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mw2020000001200010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000001600020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mj2020000006800010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mv2020000001100010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mv2020000001100010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000001200020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mj2019000023300040' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000002300020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000002300020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mf2019000004700060' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000002500040' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mv2020000001500010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mv2020000001500010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mj2020000001200010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mr2020000000100010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mw2020000001500010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000002000020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000002000100' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mb2020000001500010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2019000003600020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mg2019000006000020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000000900080' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mw2020000001600010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mw2020000001600010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mj2020000001200010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000002300020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mj2019000023300040' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000002400020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000002500040' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000001200020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mj2020000006800010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000002100020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mw2020000001700010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ml2020000003300010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'TM2019000024700100' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'TM2019000024700010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mj2019000012400010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000001600020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'TM2019000024700110' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'TM2019000024700100' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'TM2019000024700050' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000001900020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mj2019000005400010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mv2019000000100010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mr2019000000200010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mr2020000000100010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'TM2019000026000020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'TM2019000024700040' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'TM2019000024700090' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mw2020000001800010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mb2020000002000010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mg2019000006000020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mg2020000011900020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000002000100' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000002000020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2019000003600020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000002300020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'TM2020000002600010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000002400020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000002500040' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mv2020000001500010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000003200010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000002000020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000002000100' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mr2020000000100010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2019000003600020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000002700020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mv2020000001300010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000001200020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000001200020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000002400020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000002400020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000002400020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mv2020000001500010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mv2020000002500010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000002000020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000002000100' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000003400010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000003600010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mv2020000002600010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mv2020000002800010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mv2020000003000010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mv2020000002300010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000002000020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000002000100' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000003600010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mv2020000002700010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'TM2019000024700010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'TM2019000024700100' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mg2019000022700040' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mr2020000000600010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'TM2019000024700110' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mr2020000000400010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'TM2019000024700050' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mj2019000005400010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mv2019000000100010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000001200020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000001200020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000002300020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000002300020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000002300020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000004400040' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000004400040' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'TM2019000026000020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'TM2019000024700040' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'TM2019000024700090' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mr2020000000300010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000004600010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mv2020000003300010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mv2020000003200010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000003900010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000002000020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000002000100' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000003600010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mv2020000001500010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mv2020000001500010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2022000004200010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000004400040' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000004400040' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000001200020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000001200020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ml2020000002700040' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ml2020000002700040' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ml2020000002700040' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000004700010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2019000003600020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mv2020000003700010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mv2020000003600010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000004100010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mv2020000003800010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mv2020000001500010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mj2019000023300040' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000002300020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mf2019000004700060' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000002500040' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000004800010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mr2020000001200010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000004300010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mj2020000007400010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mr2020000000900010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000005100010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mf2020000010700020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000005200010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000005000010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000005500010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ms2020000000600010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000002000020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000002000100' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mv2020000001500010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000005700010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mr2020000000700010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000005600010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000005500010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2021000000100010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2019000003600020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000002000020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000002000100' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ms2020000000600010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2021000000300010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2021000000500010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mv2021000000200010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2021000000800010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2019000003600020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ms2020000000600010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2021000000900010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mv2021000000700010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'TM2019000026300010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2019000003600020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mv2020000001100010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mv2021000000500010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2021000001500010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2021000001400010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mr2020000000700010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mr2021000000100010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mj2019000012400010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mr2020000000600010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mr2020000000400010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mv2019000000100010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mr2019000000200010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mr2020000000300010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mr2020000000300010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ms2020000000600010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mj2021000005100010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mr2021000000500010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2019000003600020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mv2020000002500010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mg2020000035400020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ms2020000000600010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2019000003600020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mv2020000002900010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mv2021000001100010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2021000002000010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2021000001900010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'TM2020000002600010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000002300020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000002500040' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000002400020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2021000002200010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2021000002300010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2021000002500010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2019000000100020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mv2021000000700010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mv2021000001100010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'TM2020000002600010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000002400020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000002500040' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mv2020000002900010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2021000002300010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2021000002600010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mr2020000000700010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mr2021000000100010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mj2019000012400010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mr2020000001100010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'TM2020000003400010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mj2021000005400010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mv2019000000100010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mr2019000000200010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mv2021000001100010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'TM2020000002600010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000002400020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000002500040' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mv2020000002900010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2021000002200010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2021000002300010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2021000002600010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mr2020000001200010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2021000001200010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2021000001200010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mr2021000000500010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2021000001800010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2021000003600010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mv2020000001100010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2021000002200010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'TM2020000002600010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mj2019000023300010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mj2019000023300020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2021000002400010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2021000002300010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000002300020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2021000001800010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2021000003900010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2021000003100010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2021000003300010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2021000003800010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2021000003200010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2021000002100010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2021000002100010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mv2021000001400010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2021000002500010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mv2021000001300010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2021000003900010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2021000001800010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2021000003200010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2021000003100010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2021000002400010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2021000003300010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ms2020000000600010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mv2021000001100010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mv2021000001100010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mv2020000001100010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2021000002200010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mj2019000023300040' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000002400020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000002500040' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2021000002300010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000002300020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mr2021000000500010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mr2020000000700010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'TM2020000003400010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2021000003300010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2021000003100010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2021000003900010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2021000001800010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2021000003200010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2021000002300010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2021000002400010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'TM2020000002600010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2021000002200010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mv2021000001100010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mv2020000001100010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ms2020000000600010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2021000004100010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mv2020000001100010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2021000002400010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2021000001800010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2021000004600010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mf2019000006600020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2021000004300010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2021000001800010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2021000002400010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mv2021000001100010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mj2021000005200010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mr2021000000400010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mj2019000005400010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mr2020000000700010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mr2021000000100010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mj2019000012400010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'TM2020000003200010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'TM2020000003400010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mv2019000000100010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mr2019000000200010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'TM2020000003300010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2021000001800010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2021000002400010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mv2021000001000010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mv2020000001100010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'TM2019000026300010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2021000004500010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mv2020000001100010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2021000002400010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2021000001800010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mj2021000016300010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2022000000200010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2022000000400010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2022000000100010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2022000001100010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mv2022000000200010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2022000001300010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'TM2022000009400010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mv2021000000900010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mv2022000000100010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2022000000500010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2022000001100080' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2021000002400010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2021000001800010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mv2022000000300010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mv2022000000400010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mv2021000001000010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2020000003000020' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2021000002500010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2021000002400010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mj2022000001400010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mv2022000000400010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mv2021000001000010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2021000002400010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2022000001500010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2021000001800010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2022000002200010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ms2020000000600010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2021000002300010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2022000003200010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2022000002800010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mj2019000005400010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mr2020000000700010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mv2021000001000010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2021000001800010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mj2021000016300010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mv2021000001000010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2021000002400010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2021000002500010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2021000002300010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2022000003200010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2021000002300010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mv2022000000400010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mv2021000001000010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2021000002400010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2021000002500010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2021000004800010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2022000004100010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mv2022000000400010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mv2021000001000010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2021000002400010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2022000004100010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2022000004200010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2021000001800010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2022000002700010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2022000004000010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2021000002300010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2021000004800010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mb2022000003000010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mb2022000002900010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2021000002500010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2022000002900010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mj2019000005400010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mr2021000000100010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mr2020000000700010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mr2021000000500010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mb2022000003200010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mv2022000000400010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mv2021000001000010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mw2022000001000010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2022000004300010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ma2021000002500010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mw2022000001100010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mv2022000001200010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mb2022000003400010' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mb2022000003500010' FROM dual
)
SELECT bol.* 
  FROM BOLLER1 bol
     , (SELECT val, ROWNUM AS rn
          FROM dat) kt
 WHERE bol.BOLR1_KT1 = kt.val
 ORDER BY kt.rn;
```

**EDIT:** removed some of the rows so that the answer fits the size limits, however the principle is the same

Comment: Why `rownum` should be stable without explicit `order by` and ordering column? I think it may not be true when this statement is executed in parallel.

Comment: Wasn't sure about this so I made it explicit, it's not a big overhead anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I would write the list as a collection. This is similar to the accepted answer, but avoids a lot of verbose `select from dual union all`s.

Setup:

```
create table boller1 (bolr1_kt1 varchar2(30));

insert all
    into boller1 values ('Kitten')
    into boller1 values ('Mr2019000000400010')
    into boller1 values ('TM2019000024700100')
    into boller1 values ('TM2019000024700120')
    into boller1 values ('TM9019000024700080')
    into boller1 values ('Xenomorph')
select * from dual;
```

Query:

```
with kits (seq, kit) as (
    select rownum, column_value
    from   sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll('Xenomorph', 'Kitten', 'Mr2019000000400010', 'TM2019000024700100')
)
select b.bolr1_kt1
from   boller1 b
       join kits k on k.kit = b.bolr1_kt1
order by k.seq;
```

```
BOLR1_KT1
------------------------------
Xenomorph
Kitten
Mr2019000000400010
TM2019000024700100
```

You can use any scalar varchar2 collection type you already have, or create one with something like

```
create or replace type short_string_ntt as table of varchar2(50)
```

I just used the predefined `sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll` for demo convenience.